# Time complexity for an intersection (worst case)

Tags: time-complexity

Having trouble finding the time complexity for the worst-case time complexity. This case is for an intersection of two sort arrays of the same size (n).

Not sure how to count the while loop with two conditions or how to count the if and else if statements

I know the big 0 would be N+N but no idea how to show the worst case.

```
int printIntersection(int arr1[], int arr2[])  {
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  while (i < n && j < n) {
    if (arr1[i] < arr2[j])
      i++;
    else if (arr2[j] < arr1[i])
      j++;
    else /* if arr1[i] == arr2[j] */ {
      cout << arr2[j] << " ";
      i++;
      j++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Each iteration, at least `i` *or* `j` (or both) increment, until one of the two reaches the end of the array. Hence there are at most *m+n-1* iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that in the worst case the loop will make 2N iterations you can use the following argument.
Given two indices `i` and `j` at each step:

- if `arr1[i] < arr2[j]` then `i` is incremented by 1
- if `arr2[i] > arr1[j]` then `j` is incremented by 1
- if `arr2[i] = arr1[j]` then both `i` and `j` are incremented by 1

At each iteration *at least* one between i and j is incremented by one and the maximum number of iterations is bounded by 2N (both i and j go from 0 to n-1),
you get your resulting worst case time complexity.